# There is a way to positioning the label of radio-button above of the radio-button itself in angular material 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I'm using angular material 2 ([material.io](https://material.angular.io)) and i'm trying to put the label of the md-radio-button above of the radio itself, like this:

[Radio Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9AMU.png)

The Docs say you can easy set the position to after or before. 
I'm using flex-layout (github.com/angular/flex-layout) too.

Here is my code:

```
<md-radio-group formControlName="id_customer_type" (change)="onChangeCustomerType($event.value)">
  <md-radio-button type="radio" name="id_customer_type" value="1" [checked]="true"> Persona</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button type="radio" name="id_customer_type" value="2"> Empresa</md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button type="radio" name="id_customer_type" value="3"> IoT/M2M</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

If someone can help me, I'll be very greatful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closer to the elements created by `md-radio-group` you will notice this:

```
<label class="mat-radio-label" for="md-radio-2-input">
    <div class="mat-radio-container">
        <div class="mat-radio-outer-circle"></div>
        <div class="mat-radio-inner-circle"></div>
        <div class="mat-radio-ripple mat-ripple" md-ripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]"
             ng-reflect-centered="true" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div>
    </div>
    <input class="mat-radio-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="radio" id="md-radio-2-input" name="md-radio-group-0">
    <div class="mat-radio-label-content"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>Option 2</div>
</label>
```

`.mat-radio-label` has this CSS:

```
.mat-radio-label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Which basically is telling us that is using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to align its direct children (the radio button and the label). The default `flex-direction` is `row`, hence omitted. You can change it to column. By adding `flex-direction: column-reverse` you will put the label above.

Comment: This will work, but make sure you apply `/deep/` to override the material css class like this: `/deep/.mat-radio-label{ flex-direction: column-reverse;}`. I added a plunkr for you [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ObMtepqz2tRtHKEtgTZs?p=info)

Comment: @BogdanC, /deep/ is deprecated, should use ::ng-deep : https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: @Vega - Thanks for letting me know. From the docs looks like `::ng-deep` is going to the same path, not clear the replacement.

Comment: Finally I use this

`.radio-label-above::ng-deep.mat-radio-label{   flex-direction: column-reverse; }`
using the class .radio-label-above in md-radio-group tag I change the label position for some radios in my component. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Angular v16, and none of the solutions above work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
:host /deep/ .mat-radio-label {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  .mat-radio-label-content {
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

Using `"@angular/material": "^6.4.7"`

[image]